# Is it possible to access/edit a remote SQLite3 database with Sequelize from a website

Tags: html, node.js, remote-access, remote-server, node-sqlite3

So I have an SQLite3 database with Sequelize on a VPS and a Website I hosted on Hostinger.
Is it possible to access and edit the data in the database from the website?
Any help is appreciated.

[my code is in nodejs]

Answer (score 0):

Yes and No.
Easy and simple answer - now;

Longer - yes, but you would need to map the directories, so server running your sequelize will think it accesses normal directory. 
You can download the database, edit it and then send it back.  sqlite3 is file database, you dont really connect to it (usually)

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is a database format based on a single file. It's simple but not massively performant. It has no networking features.

The SQLite client needs to have access to the filesystem that the database lives on.

If they are on different computers, then you *could* do it by using some kind of network filesystem (e.g. via [fuse](http://blog.damontimm.com/how-to-mount-a-sftp-folder-ssh-ftp-on-ubuntu-linux-using-sshfs-fuse/)) but this would be really slow.

A better approach would be to run a webservice on the computer the file is stored on, and access the database through there.